# Copy and Paste Doesn't Work in IE8 on My Website - Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, copy-paste, internet-explorer-8

I noticed I can't copy and paste on a certain website ([Proteome Software](http://www.proteomesoftware.com)) using IE8.  I can right click and copy links and pictures, etc, but not text.  Is this my site or settings in IE8?  I have tried changing ActiveX controls, but this hasn't worked.

This functions works fine with Firefox and Chrome.

Also, it seems in IE8 I can't even drag and highlight text either.  Maybe a mouse setting?

IE8 gives this error as well:

`Webpage error details`

`User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 30 Jun 2010 20:19:52 UTC`

`Message: 'menu' is undefined
Line: 344
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://www.proteomesoftware.com/`

`Message: Object expected
Line: 110
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.proteomesoftware.com/`

I investigated these lines in my `index.html` file and it seems there are some missing PNG files for the **Object expected** error but the **menu** error is not clear to me.

Comment: You could try asking on doctype.com. This is more along their lines than superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's got something to do with Accelerators.  I can double-click on the text for this page and it highlights, and then clicking again highlights the whole chuck of text.  Oddly, though, when doing this, IE gives me an icon for Accelerators.  I can't seem to disable this function, but I can turn them off.  Still doesn't allow for copying just one text digit.